# Alternatives to GameKIt for iPhone to iPhone transfer

Tags: iphone, bonjour, gamekit

I am needing to transfer information as an NSData object from one iPhone to another inside an application and was originally planning on using Bluetooth/GameKit, but the data looks like it will be in the neighborhood of 500KB -> 1MB in size.  I don't think this is going to fly with GameKit (Bluetooth) as it will take forever and it seems like people are having all kinds of issues with GK anyway.

I'd prefer the users to not have to be on the same WiFi network to make it work but am running out of options and time so I'd probably be happy with whatever works.

What is a reasonable alternative?  The simpler the setup the better or something with sample code would be greatly appreciated and preferred.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with a project I am working on.  Battled around with GK for awhile before having to relent to the fact that I would need my own networking code and would have to restrict users to being on the same LAN.  I use Bonjour for discovery and then manage the connection myself.  Not really an answer, but a shared experience may give you some confidence in your design decision.

Comment: I agree with Kenny. I've had a very similar experience; GameKit and bluetooth are messy and unreliable.